# ASP.NET MVC routes with username /username/section vs /section/username

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I was just wondering which routing style most people would use to have a username with various sections using ASP.NET MVC 3?

```
/username/profile
/username/settings
/username/details
```

vs

```
/profile/username
/settings/username
/details/username
```

If the first style was chosen how would you handle the routes?

Comment: will  users be able to access other users profile, setting and details pages?

Comment: The idea is that I would like to have others users see only the detail page of other users. The profile and settings sections should only be visible to yourself not see other users ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your reply in the comment I would structure it as

/Settings

/Profile

and

/Username

When a user goes to /Settings or /Profile they will only see their own details.

when they go to /Username they will see the users profile (be it their own or someone else's).

your Global asax will need the appropriate routes set up to make this work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, with this idea would I have to ensure that I have reserved words so a username can't be Profile, Settings etc?

Comment: yes in this model the user wont be allowed to have a name the same as any of your controllers and cant set their username as "Profile" or "Settings"...you shouln't have to worry about that though.

Answer (score 1):

As @raklos asked in a comment, it really depends on how the application is structured. To me, the left-most parts of a URL are more important that those to the right.

So, in your top design, the User is the most important part, and each user has different sections of stuff.

On the other hand, in the bottom design, the sections are the important parts and for each section, you could look at that information for a particular user.

For me, the most natural feels like the top one, because the profile, settings, and details are going to be unique for each user, so the concept is that a user *has* the various sections, rather than each section having various users. It also would seem more flexible/natural for some users to have more/less sections than other users, rather than some sections having more/less users than other sections.